# How to get time between two dates in hh:mm:ss format in react native?

Tags: react-native, momentjs, gettime

i have start date and end date like below mentioned

"start_date":"2019-05-21 10:00:00",
"end_date":"2019-07-31 23:59:59",

how to get a time difference between two dates in hh:mm:ss format ..i m new to react native

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224834/get-difference-between-2-dates-in-javascript

Comment: above links are not working for me as i my date format is different

Answer (score 0):

`let start_date = "2019-05-21 10:00:00",
    end_date = "2019-07-31 23:59:59";`

I think You are using moment to get this date time. You can find the difference using moment itself.

`let difference = moment(start_date,"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss").diff(moment(end_date,"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss"));`

`let time = moment.duration(difference)`

You can format the result in any way you want using [moment-duration-format](https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format).